# Interactive HTML plots from Python's Bokeh to Latex

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, latex, bokeh

I would like to embed an interactive HTML based plot (For example, http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/gallery/burtin.html)
in a pdf document that I generated using latex. I am able to embed matplotlib based plots in my document using pythontex. I however fail to embed  html based plots as shown above.

I would be extremely grateful for any insights. As long as they allow me to embed interactive plots, I am open to using platforms other than latex (even Microsoft Word) except for Python notebooks.  I paste my code below. Thank you very much in advance for your time.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{graphicx }

\begin{document}


\begin{pycode} 
from collections import OrderedDict
from math import log, sqrt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from six.moves import cStringIO as StringIO

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

antibiotics = """
bacteria,                        penicillin, streptomycin, neomycin, gram
Mycobacterium tuberculosis,      800,        5,            2,        negative
Salmonella schottmuelleri,       10,         0.8,          0.09,     negative
Proteus vulgaris,                3,          0.1,          0.1,      negative
Klebsiella pneumoniae,           850,        1.2,          1,        negative
Brucella abortus,                1,          2,            0.02,     negative
Pseudomonas aeruginosa,          850,        2,            0.4,      negative
Escherichia coli,                100,        0.4,          0.1,      negative
Salmonella (Eberthella) typhosa, 1,          0.4,          0.008,    negative
Aerobacter aerogenes,            870,        1,            1.6,      negative
Brucella antracis,               0.001,      0.01,         0.007,    positive
Streptococcus fecalis,           1,          1,            0.1,      positive
Staphylococcus aureus,           0.03,       0.03,         0.001,    positive
Staphylococcus albus,            0.007,      0.1,          0.001,    positive
Streptococcus hemolyticus,       0.001,      14,           10,       positive
Streptococcus viridans,          0.005,      10,           40,       positive
Diplococcus pneumoniae,          0.005,      11,           10,       positive
"""

drug_color = OrderedDict([
("Penicillin",   "#0d3362"),
("Streptomycin", "#c64737"),
("Neomycin",     "black"  ),
])

gram_color = {
    "positive" : "#aeaeb8",
    "negative" : "#e69584",
}

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(antibiotics),
skiprows=1,
skipinitialspace=True,
engine='python')

width = 800
height = 800
inner_radius = 90
outer_radius = 300 - 10

minr = sqrt(log(.001 * 1E4))
maxr = sqrt(log(1000 * 1E4))
a = (outer_radius - inner_radius) / (minr - maxr)
b = inner_radius - a * maxr

def rad(mic):
return a * np.sqrt(np.log(mic * 1E4)) + b

big_angle = 2.0 * np.pi / (len(df) + 1)
small_angle = big_angle / 7

x = np.zeros(len(df))
y = np.zeros(len(df))

output_file("burtin.html", title="burtin.py example")

p = figure(plot_width=width, plot_height=height, title="",
x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None,
x_range=[-420, 420], y_range=[-420, 420],
min_border=0, outline_line_color="black",
background_fill="#f0e1d2", border_fill="#f0e1d2")

p.line(x+1, y+1, alpha=0)

# annular wedges
angles = np.pi/2 - big_angle/2 - df.index.to_series()*big_angle
colors = [gram_color[gram] for gram in df.gram]
p.annular_wedge(
x, y, inner_radius, outer_radius, -big_angle+angles, angles, color=colors,
)

# small wedges
p.annular_wedge(x, y, inner_radius, rad(df.penicillin),
-big_angle+angles+5*small_angle, -big_angle+angles+6*small_angle,
color=drug_color['Penicillin'])
p.annular_wedge(x, y, inner_radius, rad(df.streptomycin),
-big_angle+angles+3*small_angle, -big_angle+angles+4*small_angle,
color=drug_color['Streptomycin'])
p.annular_wedge(x, y, inner_radius, rad(df.neomycin),
-big_angle+angles+1*small_angle, -big_angle+angles+2*small_angle,
color=drug_color['Neomycin'])

# circular axes and lables
labels = np.power(10.0, np.arange(-3, 4))
radii = a * np.sqrt(np.log(labels * 1E4)) + b
p.circle(x, y, radius=radii, fill_color=None, line_color="white")
p.text(x[:-1], radii[:-1], [str(r) for r in labels[:-1]],
text_font_size="8pt", text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")

# radial axes
p.annular_wedge(x, y, inner_radius-10, outer_radius+10,
-big_angle+angles, -big_angle+angles, color="black")

# bacteria labels
xr = radii[0]*np.cos(np.array(-big_angle/2 + angles))
yr = radii[0]*np.sin(np.array(-big_angle/2 + angles))
label_angle=np.array(-big_angle/2+angles)
label_angle[label_angle < -np.pi/2] += np.pi # easier to read labels on the left side
p.text(xr, yr, df.bacteria, angle=label_angle,
text_font_size="9pt", text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")

# OK, these hand drawn legends are pretty clunky, will be improved in future release
p.circle([-40, -40], [-370, -390], color=list(gram_color.values()), radius=5)
p.text([-30, -30], [-370, -390], text=["Gram-" + gr for gr in gram_color.keys()],
text_font_size="7pt", text_align="left", text_baseline="middle")

p.rect([-40, -40, -40], [18, 0, -18], width=30, height=13,
color=list(drug_color.values()))
p.text([-15, -15, -15], [18, 0, -18], text=list(drug_color.keys()),
text_font_size="9pt", text_align="left", text_baseline="middle")

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p) 

\end{pycode}

\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{burtin.html}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure. Please find my code attached above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As of Bokeh `0.12.1` this is not possible. Although Bokeh is a "Python" library, it was designed and conceived for the purpose of making it simple to make interactive visualizations in the browser. Accordingly, it has large JavaScript component (where all the work is done, actually), and requires a running JavaScript engine (i.e. a web browser) to function.

There is a "save tool" that will let you save PNGs from a web page by manually clicking a button, but that is it. Additionally methods in 
`bokeh.export` can be used to generate static PNGs or SVGs from Python.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing. Much appreciated. Any idea on other ways to include interactive plots in Latex?

Comment: Are you asking about having actually interactive elements in the final docuemnt? I assumed you wanted to generate a static image of an interactive Bokeh plot and use that. Frankly I don't think embedding an actually interactive plot is possible. TeX was not created (~30 years ago) with these use cases in mind, and AFAIK the PDF output format does not admit anything that would enable interactivity either. It's possible that the knowledge informing that opinion is somehow out of date, but if so I don't know anything that would help.